# Can PHP classes return object of type interface that they are implementing?

Tags: php, oop, static, factory

When concreate classes implement interface, do they return object of type interface that they are implementing? In typical factory pattern scenario the concrete classes return object of type interface they are implementing (for java and C# this is true). Does this happen in case of PHP also?

Consider the following situation..

```
interface IUser
{
  function getName();
}

class User implements IUser
{
  public function __construct( $id ) { }

  public function getName()
  {
    return "Jack";
  }
}

class UserFactory
{
  public static function Create( $id )
  {
    return new User( $id );
  }
}

$uo = UserFactory::Create( 1 );
echo( $uo->getName()."\n" );
```

Is object **$uo** an instance of type IUser or User, and why?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the type of $ou?

Comment: It's both, actually. `$uo` is both `IUser` and `User`. But `get_class($uo)` will get you `'User'`.

Comment: Oh and may i recommend to not use STATIC in your classes. It makes for poor testability and often leads to singleton approaches and tight coupling which is in many cases really not recommended. http://crazycoders.net/from-tight-coupling-to-dependency-inversion-stupid-series/

Comment: @Hammerstein, yes, i tried to tak a look at the it. It returned user.

Comment: @raina77ow, Hmm, Thanks. is that true for other languages like java also, where we can specify the return type as IUser? Can we do similar here also?

Comment: @Hammerstein. How to do that in way so that loose coupling prevails?
We need an object of that UserFactory to use the Create method then. How does that promote loose coupling?

Comment: Loose coupling or the solid pattern Interface Segregation is a good way to code an application because you rely on the interface implementation (usually minimal) instead of a class implementation... Then, it means that objects can implement two interfaces and be valid in totally different contexts making your application much more flexible in it's changing patterns.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin, Ok, I get that. How does using STATIC in classes leads to tight coupling?

Comment: Anything static refers to a global existence of a variable. If you use a static/global variable, you create a tight coupling to either the global variable that you created or to the class name and its static property. If you refer to a static variable of a class, it is not possible to use interfaces anymore and you assume the existing of something that should not exist unless part of a testable code branch. Static private or protected properties have much less impact on thight coupling since they are only available to the current class or it's children!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never return an interface or a class, you return an object that implements the class of your choice which in turn will implement an interface.

An interface or class is the declaration and definition portion of the object that you create while the object is variable that contains the properties. Any call you do to an object resolves to a class and the body of that function is executed, but the properties you access (the non-static ones) return to the object itself.

When instanciating an object of a certain class, the object is OF that class. It cannot be of the type of an interface because an interface cannot be instanciated. On the other hand, you can use "instanceof" in PHP to determine if an object implements a certain interface or uses a specific class. Instanceof validates all interfaces implemented in all classes of the object, even the parent ones.

So using:

```
interface i {}
interface i2 {}
class a implements i {}
class b extends a {}
class c extends b implements i2 {}
$o = new b();
```

In this very case, $o is an "i", "a" and "b". All calls to instanceof with these class names will return true... But because $o is ob class b naturally, instanceof will never return true for the C class or the i2 interface.

Comment: Take a look at the code here..
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm
Shape is an interface. 
In the factory class we see the program returns an object of a class that implements the interface Shape, which is again of type Shape. 
Check here.. 
//Code...
public Shape getShape(String shapeType){
Is this possible in java then and not in PHP?

Comment: Totally possible, it's just that there are no return types in PHP so you can't say for sure it will be an object of interface Shape that will be returned...

Answer (score 1):

As @raina77ow pointed out in comments, it's actually both.

You can check using `instanceof`

```
var_dump( get_class($uo) ); // User

var_dump(($uo instanceof IUser)); // true

var_dump(($uo instanceof User)); // true
```

From [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php):

> Lastly, instanceof can also be used to determine whether a variable is an instantiated object of a class that implements an interface: